# Flutter: 'Stream has already been listened to.'

Tags: flutter, dart, stream-builder

I have a `DefaultTabController` with two tabs which work fine. On my second tab I have recently added a `stream controller` to update a value on screen everytime that value changes which also works fine, but if I was to swift left to the first tab then back to the second I get the following error.

`Stream has already been listened to.`

I have a dispose function but due to not navigating to another page it does not trigger so it create many stream, which I don't want it to do.

All the code below is for the stream controller, if I comment all this code out, the app works fine without the error and ive also found out if I comment out only `stream: stream_controller.stream,` I also dont get the error.

```
StreamController<int> stream_controller = StreamController<int>();
```

```
@override
  void dispose(){
    super.dispose();
    stream_controller.close();
   
  }
```

```
StreamBuilder(
                                          initialData: 0,
                                          stream: stream_controller.stream,
                                          builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                            return Padding(
                                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                              child: Text(
                                                '#${snapshot.data}',
                                              ),
                                            );
                                          })
```

```
 stream_controller.sink.add(rank);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Stream<T>`s can only be listened once. To enable any number of listeners, use:

```dart
StreamController<int> stream_controller = StreamController<int>.broadcast();
```

Also in your context seems you're reusing the same `StreamController` instance. Try defining it inside `initState` rather of as class field:

```dart
class _MyState extends State<T> {
  late StreamController<int> stream_controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    stream_controller = StreamController<int>.broadcast();
  }

  @override
  void dispose(){
    stream_controller.close();
    super.dispose();
  } 
}
```

> A broadcast stream allows any number of listeners, and it fires its events when they are ready, whether there are listeners or not.

See complete [`Stream` documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-async/Stream-class.html) for details.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, but would somehow triggering dispose when I swipe to tab 1 be a better option?

Comment: not really. It truly depends on what behavior do you want achieve. If you ran in trouble by using this way (buggy behavior or exception) you need to debug to find the cause and then see if moving the dispose to another tree location can help you.